# Can I define an interface that has optional attributes but if one is defined all have to be defined?

Tags: typescript

I have

```
interface SomeInterface {
  a: string;
  b?: string;
  c?: string;
}
```

And I would like to have two kinds of objects created using this Interface => only with { a } attribute or with { a, b, c } attributes, I would like to Typescript does not allow me to create { a, b } or { a, c } Objects

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not use a union: `{ a: string } | { a: string; b: string; c: string }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type, perhaps like this:

```
type SomeInterface = 
  { a: string, b?: never, c?: never } | 
  { a: string, b: string, c: string };
```

Note that this is a [type alias and not an interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces), so the name "`SomeInterface`" is a bit unfortunate.  Interfaces cannot be unions, so you have to do this as a type alias.  There are a few places in TypeScript where the distinction between type aliases and interfaces is important, but mostly they are interchangeable.  It ultimately depends on your use case.

Anyway, that says a `SomeInterface` is either a type where both `b` and `c` properties are missing (`b?: never` means that `b` is optional but cannot have a defined value if it is present), or where both `b` and `c` properties are present with a `string` value.  You can verify that this works:

```
const x: SomeInterface = { a: "okay" };
const y: SomeInterface = { a: "okay", b: "okay", c: "okay" };
const z: SomeInterface = { a: "okay", b: "oops" }; // error!
//    ~ <-- Type '{ a: string; b: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SomeInterface'.
```

Also, the compiler can use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to check a value of type `SomeInterface` to see which of the two union members it is:

```
function foo(w: SomeInterface) {
  if (w.b !== undefined) {
    w.c.toUpperCase(); // okay, the compiler understand that c is defined here
  }
}
```

which is neat.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKglgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIDKB7AtjASWnmTXQG8AoddJALnQGco5IBzAbmvQCMB+Bs1YRO3FAKYt2XAL4hglSlACeABww58RWIlQYAvBVqCpIgDS8JEGADd4F8Q2t246GegA+R+pOFsLPCZ+DkHsblyUKNgQzOgAHgyahMS6ZIbkxugARNgA1kjKWeGR0bHKiXjJOqQG3gw5+YUB9XkFWSHZrYXFUTFQ6ABeFVopNejpmQ1tzZ3YqoxFMhzowMDo8HDYcACElKs0NAB+6AA8ALRn6AAqahgA5Bk+QtK8oSLLMnfoYIzoENj9JCMRhgNgQJA8AA2GCg2HQKnU6DuSW0JD0dwAdIoEABXCAoKBgaLoBDYbAACgA7sMqmi0ABKCjcMAIdBUjE8dDbfSGPEAExgCEgMD5jKoB3QlIxKAxsIAqqp1HAAMJAmDk+nLfZdCxQAAWGCiuFUYGhrn58GYSAgfPheqQ-RQ31+AqF1ltBrgMG4MkoMiAA)